# 403 response when making a get request

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services

I'm getting a 403 response when making a get request to this website (https://volusia.county-taxes.com) using python3 in aws EC2 server. But I'm getting success response in my local system using same code.

Please help me. Why im not able to make a get request in aws ec2 server?

In aws EC2 server

```py
import requests
requests.get('https://volusia.county-taxes.com')
```

`<Response [403]>`

In my local system

```py
import requests
requests.get('https://volusia.county-taxes.com')
```

`<Response [200]>`

Comment: in your local environment are you trying access that page in browser or by using request library?

Comment: in my terminal using requests library

Answer (score 1):

Can't say for sure, but a 403 is a 'forbidden' code, and it is not all that unusual for some websites to block traffic from the ec2 ip ranges to cut down on the number of bots/scrapers that tend to abuse websites and are often run on aws and other cloud providers.

Its possible that either the entire ec2 ip range is blocked, or else just some of the ips - especially if you have been running some sort of scraper from that ip, it may be blacklisted.

Comment: Is there any solution for this blocking ?